# Why is the memo hash different from the one I specify during tx building?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, memo

I'm converting IPFS multi hash to hex, and after throwing away its prefix I want to attach that hash to a stellar transaction (something like [here](http://abcxyz.de/2018/02/08/using-ipfs-as-memo-in-stellar-transaction/)). I build it this way:

```
let transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
    .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: supply,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: MIN,
    }))
    .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.hash(hash))
    .build();
transaction.sign(pair);
```

At runtime let's say the hash value is:

```
8c339e15bd89e7f8c7d6c754b8016a202bba12a8cdb4aabe39c6c9e30507a8f3
```

But after consensus has been reached, I retrieve the same transaction and it shows a different value for the memo hash:

```
memo: "jDOeFb2J5/jH1sdUuAFqICu6EqjNtKq+OcbJ4wUHqPM="
memo_type: "hash"
```

Why?

Comment: Just found this out myself... is this included in the developer docs - could be useful for many. https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/5886/get-original-value-from-memo-hash/5889#5889

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I'm not sure why this happens, this is not a different hash, its just encoded in base64

```
   >>> import base64
   >>> base64.b64decode('jDOeFb2J5/jH1sdUuAFqICu6EqjNtKq+OcbJ4wUHqPM=').hex()
   '8c339e15bd89e7f8c7d6c754b8016a202bba12a8cdb4aabe39c6c9e30507a8f3'
```

Comment: I'm doing it like this bs58.decode(multiHash).slice(2).toString('hex'); and get the hex string, this is strange

Comment: Base64 encoding is what is used to store the data on the blockchain as it is more compact. In most cases, in js-stellar-sdk, the values are stored as buffer. You can get back to hex using something like `buffer.toString('hex')`

Comment: @MisterTicot What's stored on the blockchain is the actual 256-bit binary string. Base64 encoding is just used as a representation to get printable characters.

Comment: Ok after retrieving the memo hash it is sufficient to do this let buffer = Buffer.from(txs[0].memo, 'base64'); let string = buffer.toString('hex');

Comment: @JohanStén Of course you're right. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @MaximGaina, your solution works fine on my nodejs application, thanks :)