# Get Original value from Memo.Hash

Tags: javascript-sdk, xdr

I used a Hash input in the Memo.Hash and submitted the transaction. How can i read the memo field back?

input memo: ec8186367ee56880f7c48d4ae28ecd6cdafa455e8e49d35a691f41d95bcf95e6
trxn "memo": "7IGGNn7laID3xI1K4o7NbNr6RV6OSdNaaR9B2VvPleY="

How can i retrive the original hash input memo from the trxn?

this is the transaction on testnet
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/ed7646b7e9bc1ad37a4068156ffc6680cf206da54739f7c045baef6729b9ea35

Comment: i am thinking this field is in xdr format. would that be a correct inference ?    "memo": "7IGGNn7laID3xI1K4o7NbNr6RV6OSdNaaR9B2VvPleY="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - the memo field in the final transaction is in base64 and not XDR. so a base64 > hex conversion will give the original hex input.